# If modified since with (replace www) modrewrite-rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, if-modified-since

i only use the my domain http://myDomain.com and not http://www.myDomain.com,
so i use this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

my problem is, that i always get an 301 redirect -> even when i visit my domain without www

Any ideas to fix this?

**My goal is:**

```
http://www.myDomain.com -> 301
http://myDomain.com -> 304 Not Modified
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: rules should work fine, try to clear the browser cache

Comment: strange ... this tool "http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/if-modified/" said -> redirect 301